# Regex search/replace not returning expected results

Tags: regex, notepad++

Odd issue. I have the following sample text in Notepad++:

```
<p>Header #1<br />
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/ignumber1">Instagram</a><br />
Header #2<br />
<a href="http://example.com">Blog</a> | <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/ytnumber2/">Youtube</a> | <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ignumber2">Instagram</a><br />
```

Here's my regex search:

`<a href="([^|]*)">Instagram<\/a>`

And replace:

`"IG": "\1",\n`

I do a search, search mode is regular expression, ". matches newline" does not appear to make a difference (I've tried both ways). After the search/replace all, I expect to get:

```
<p>Header #1<br />
"IG": "https://www.instagram.com/ignumber1",
<br />
Header #2<br />
<a href="http://example.com">Blog</a> | <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/ytnumber2/">Youtube</a> | "IG": "https://www.instagram.com/ignumber2",
<br />
```

I actually get:

```
<p>Header #1<br />
"IG": "https://www.instagram.com/ignumber1",
<br />
Header #2<br />
<a href="http://example.com">Blog</a> | <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/ytnumber2/">Youtube</a> | "IG": "https://www.instagram.com/ignumber2">Instagram</a><br />
```

So it worked properly under Header #1, but not under Header #2, and I'm a bit perplexed as to why.

Many thanks. :)

Comment: If I copy and paste your example into a new document and your expressions into the replace dialog in an up to date version of Notepad++, it replaces exactly as expected. There is possibly something wrong with the encoding of the original file, or perhaps you're missing some special character that didn't come across to this post. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Thanks for checking, Grismar. The original text I'm working with is copied from Chrome | View Source, pasted into a new NP++ document, and not yet saved at the time of the search/replace. The only thing that's changing between there and here is I'm changing the identifiable parts of the links and headers. I'll give it another shot in the morning and  try saving the document first, and see if that makes a difference. Oh, and I'm working with NP++ 32-bit v7.8.4. Thanks again.

Comment: Why are you using `[^|]*`? Probably you actually mean `[^"]*`?

Comment: without [^|]*, it lumps together the blog link and the YT link, or the YT link and the Instagram link, under Header #2. [^|]* means "any character except |", which effectively keeps them from being separated by the separator. ...Oh, I see what you're saying. I'll give that a shot, thanks. :)